# Troubles Identifying a Cell Position using Gspread on Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am writing a Python script using gspread to read and write data to a Google Sheet.  One of the tasks that this script has to do is set the background color of any empty cell in a given column to black.  I am attempting to read the sheet data just once into a dictionary called `data` using `data = sheet.get_all_records()`, then formatting the cell based on the dictionary's data, however I am running into a problem.  `worksheet.format()` seems to only accept cells in 'A1' notation (that's all that it shows in the docs about formatting cells, and any attempts at other formats throws errors), but the cell object that I have by calling `sheet.find(userDict[column])`, where `userDict[]` is an element of `data`, returns its row and column as an integer.  Is there a nice way to have a cell object return its position in 'A1' notation?  If not, I suspect the easiest way would be to convert `cell.col` to the appropriate character using ASCII values, but I'm hoping there's a more elegant way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- For the specific column, you want to set the background color of the cells which are empty.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve all values from the sheet.
2. Retrieve the row numbers of the cells which are empty.
3. Set the background color of the cells using batchUpdate method.

When this flow is reflected in the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```py
client = gspread.authorize(credentials) # Please use your authorization script.

spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet name.
checkColumns = [1, 3] # Please set the column number. In this sample, 1 and 3 means columns "A" and "C", respectively.

# 1. Retrieve all values from the sheet.
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName)
data = sheet.get_all_values()

# 2. Retrieve the row numbers of the cells which are the empty.
transposed = [list(e) for e in zip(*data)]
rowNumbers = [[i for i, v in enumerate(transposed[e - 1]) if not v] for e in checkColumns]

# 3. Set background color of the cells using batchUpdate method.
requests = []
for i, e in enumerate(checkColumns):
    if rowNumbers[i] != []:
        for f in rowNumbers[i]:
            requests.append({
                "updateCells": {
                    "range": {"sheetId": sheet.id, "startRowIndex": f, "endRowIndex": f + 1, "startColumnIndex": e - 1, "endColumnIndex": e},
                    "rows": [{"values": [{"userEnteredFormat": {"backgroundColor": {"red": 0, "green": 0, "blue": 0}}}]}],
                    "fields": "userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor"
                }
            })
res = spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": requests})
```

- When this script is run, the background color of the empty cells of the specific columns is set as the black color.

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v4.0.1/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)